# Ruby compass compiler using java

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, compass-sass

I am using compass compiler inside my java application. Basically, I am executing Process to launch compass.
The question is... Is it possible to use some tool/framework like JRuby to execute compass compiler task without installing any dependencies(Ruby) on my environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a command in ruby (and therefore JRuby) using backticks, for example:

```
puts `compass version`
```